# How can i adjust vertical distance between formulation?

Tags: equations

I want to formulation not to stick together, somehow have reasonable distance. How can i do that?

```
\begin{equation}
P_{ng}\geq P_g^{min}~~\forall g\in\Omega^{G-n},\forall n\in\Omega^N~:~\alpha_{ng}^{min}\geq 0\\
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
-P_{ng}\geq -P_g^{max}~~\forall g\in\Omega^{G-n},\forall n\in\Omega^N~:~\alpha_{ng}^{max}\geq 0\\
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
P_{\ell}\geq -P_\ell^{max}\cdot Z_\ell~~\forall \ell\in\Omega^{\ell}~:~\beta_\ell^{min}\geq 0\\
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
-P_{\ell}\geq -P_\ell^{max}\cdot Z_\ell~~\forall \ell\in\Omega^{\ell}~:~\beta_\ell^{max}\geq 0\\
\end{equation}
```

Comment: you should never have `equation` environments one after the other, use ams multi-line math environments such as `align` or `multline`. also `max` should be `\mathrm{max}` You can not use `\\ ` in `equation`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As David Carlisle has already pointed out in a comment, you shouldn't use multiple consecutive `equation` environments -- use either an `align` environment (if you want to align the equations on a certain axis, see below) or a `gather` environment (if alignment isn't needed).

I suggest you use an `align` environment, replace all instances of `~~` with `\qquad`, and all instances of `~:~` with `\text{ s.t.\ }`.

The default vertical distances between the lines of the `align` environment look OK to me. If you want more separation, try `\\[2ex]` instead of just `\\` as the line-breaking command.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} %% for "align" environment
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
P_{ng}&\geq \phantom{-} P_g^{\min} 
\qquad  \forall g\in\Omega^{G-n},\forall n\in\Omega^N\text{ s.t.\ }\alpha_{ng}^{\min}\geq 0\\
-P_{ng}&\geq -P_g^{\max} 
\qquad  \forall g\in\Omega^{G-n},\forall n\in\Omega^N\text{ s.t.\ }\alpha_{ng}^{\max}\geq 0\\
P_{\ell}&\geq -P_\ell^{\max}\cdot Z_\ell 
\qquad  \forall \ell\in\Omega^{\ell}\text{ s.t.\ }\beta_\ell^{\min}\geq 0\\
-P_{\ell}&\geq -P_\ell^{\max}\cdot Z_\ell 
\qquad  \forall \ell\in\Omega^{\ell}\text{ s.t.\ }\beta_\ell^{\max}\geq 0
\end{align} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think a construction like this is improved by using alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{4}
P_{ng}    &\geq P_g^{\min}                &\quad&  \forall g\in\Omega^{G-n},\forall n\in\Omega^N &:&~&\alpha_{ng}^{\min}\geq 0\\
-P_{ng}   &\geq -P_g^{\max}               &&  \forall g\in\Omega^{G-n},\forall n\in\Omega^N      &:&&\alpha_{ng}^{\max}\geq 0\\
P_{\ell}  &\geq -P_\ell^{\max}\cdot Z_\ell&&  \forall \ell\in\Omega^{\ell}                       &:&&\beta_\ell^{\min}\geq 0\\
-P_{\ell} &\geq -P_\ell^{\max}\cdot Z_\ell&&  \forall \ell\in\Omega^{\ell}                       &:&&\beta_\ell^{\max}\geq 0
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

[image: alignat]

The `alignat` environment comes from the [amsmath package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath); [mathmode.pdf](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode) by Herbert Voss contains some more details about this. You can add extra vertical space by using an optional argument to `\\` (e.g. `\\[4mm]`) or put

```
\addtolength\jot{4mm}
```

immediately before `\begin{alignat}` to add spaces between all of the lines. You may want to reduce `\jot` just after the end of the environment; otherwise this will affect later alignment environments as well.